# Syntax error on token Android Development error

Tags: android

I am a bit new to Android development, and I received this error when trying to create an Intent which starts another activity called areacircle:

```
Syntax error on token "(",; expected  
Syntax error on token ")",; expected   
void is an invalid type for the variable acircle
```

**EDIT: I ADDED THE WHOLE BLOCK OF CODE**

I hope this code can help you help me:

```
public class findmy extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findmy);


    public void acircle(View view) {
        Intent acircleIntent = new Intent(this, areacircle.class);
        startActivity(acircleIntent);
                }
            }
```

}

Comment: learn java syntax first ... it is not a runtime error ...

Comment: Are there any fixes I can make to this code?

Comment: yes, check all your brackets and semicolons

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public void acircle(View view) {
Intent acircleIntent = new Intent(this, areacircle.class);
startActivity(acircleIntent);
        };
    }
```

To:

Remove `;` from fourth line after `}` and your problem should be gone.

```
public void acircle(View view) {
Intent acircleIntent = new Intent(this, areacircle.class);
startActivity(acircleIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is still there! Would you like me to send entire code to you?

Comment: I am so sorry, but what exactly is the stacktrace? I am still new this! And I added all the code, if that helps!

Comment: at the bottom of your code, there must be a tab called logcat. Post its contents here. Or send me the code

Comment: There are no contents containing in LogCat, but I edited my initial post by adding the full code

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you are staring another activity on button click

```
public class findmy extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findmy);
    Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTitle3);
    d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent acircleIntent = new Intent(this, areacircle.class);
            startActivity(acircleIntent);
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Comment: I get the error: 
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){},Class<areacircle>) is undefined

Comment: Check that you have areacircle.java in src folder of your project. And add areacircleactivity in your manifest